# ¿Por que no funciona el inicio en boot con versiones mas recientes de android?

Tags: android, android-studio, boot

He programado que mi app de pruebas se inicie al arrancar el dispositivo móvil, solo funciona con Android 7 y versiones antiguas. En teléfonos con Android mas nuevos no funciona correctamente, aparece el Toast pero no inicia el MainActivity.java ¿Alguien sabe porque?

````
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Bootstart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Inicio de BOOT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
}  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conozco que existan cambios que influyan en que no funcione en versiones recientes de Android el detectar un BOOT_COMPLETED, pero el código que muestras no va a realizar alguna acción al iniciar completamente tu dispositivo. Lo que debes realizar es:

Primeramente debes agregar el permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml:`

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**Registrar el servicio e indicar que se iniciara este servicio cuando se realiza `BOOT_COMPLETED`**:

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jorgesys.startupapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.jorgesys.startupapp.LauncherApp" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Te sugiero revises este ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-start-app-on-BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Muchas gracias, me resolvió la duda.

Comment: Excelente, que bien que solucionaste el problema @Lovezno , saludos.